# Google play in-app v3 : upgrading from v2 to v3 = no item in inventory but item already owned when trying to buy

Tags: android, in-app-billing, google-play

I have an old app using InApp Billing v2. Which work well.
I Want to upgrade it to InApp Billing v3, like other of my apps succefully updated. So i use the Google Sample iabhelper, and use it with my public key / products (no change made, just use the same infos).

Before update, i had already buyed the inapp product (full version unlock/non consumable/managed).

With my update, the "query inventory async" return an empty inventory But when i push the button to buy the product, google give me an error "already owned/buyed".

I already had cleared google play store cache, uninstall/reinstall apps, reboot my device (that do it on multiple device using my account).

At launch, all seems to work without any errors display (all debug log say OK).

I don't know what to do... So if someone have any idea...

EDIT : i'm testing it with release signed apk (with same version as on the store version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ! I finally found a solution... I use billing V2(restore) AND V3(restore+buy)... It's really horrible to have to do that but i found no other solution... :X

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up your item as "not managed".
2. After the payment you have to consume each paid item (it's like it was in status "paid" and gets the status "delivered"). After consuming you can buy it again.

In common the scheme looks like this:
- you ask play store app to provide user payment for specified item
- play store app gives you callback with payment status
- you check the status and do all your magic about paid item
- then you tell to play store app "ok, I've processed this payment, you can let user pay for it again"

Comment: I can't do that, because it's an "unlock full version" inapp. So when i buy it, i want to see it in the "query inventory" request. I don't want to make consumable inapp like "freemium games". if a user reinstall my app, i want to see that he had already buyed the full version.